# Is Sydney - Papeete - Easter Island - Santiago possible on a round the world ticket?

Tags: flight-search-engines, around-the-world, tahiti, easter-island

Is Sydney - Papeete - Easter Island - Santiago possible on a round the world ticket?

I've looked at the rules for RTW tickets and can see no reason why not. However, I've not been able to put together such an itinerary on any site either.

After Santiago, assume I continue East and return to Sydney via Africa. It's not that part which is proving difficult.

Comment: @JoeBlow I would not agree with this, although perhaps I wonder if we are actually talking about different things. First, RTW tickets are in no sense discounted, unless you originate from curious places like MPM. Mostly they are significantly overpriced compared to other fares. Second, they are restricted by airline, not by airport. Third the xGLOBx fare is in every respect a RTW fare, it's even similarly priced to the xONEx product. oneworld doesn't advertise it because they'd rather you stayed on oneworld metal.

Comment: @Calchas - fair enough, I get your points!  Good one.

Comment: I was looking into RTW on the basis that Papeete and Easter Island are both expensive places to fly to.  And I would be going past on SYD-SCL anyway. :)  Plus I wouldn't mind going to the Skeleton Coast..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

(This answer will become invalid for trips commencing after LATAM leaves oneworld.)

## Answer.

Yes, but you have to purchase a particular fare that is not usually advertised (a oneworld *global* explorer fare, sometimes called a `xGLOBx` fare, to be distinguished from the more usual oneworld explorer fare, an `xONEx`). Any competent travel agent can arrange this for you, if you know what to ask.

No internet site is capable of pricing `xGLOBx` fares, it has to be done by hand.

The specific fare will be an `LGLOB26` (economy), a `DGLOB26` (business) or an `AGLOB26` (first class, but none of the flights on your route offer first so this would be a waste).

Out of Sydney, an `LGLOB26` is presently priced at AUD  2799.00, plus fees, taxes and surcharges. The fees, taxes and surcharges depend on what countries you enter, which airports you land at and which carriers you fly on; but I would be surprised if they came to more than 1000 AUD. This fare permits up to 26,000 miles of travel, which should be sufficient for [your purposes](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=SYD-AKL-PPT-IPC-SCL-GRU-JNB-SYD).

[Indeed, you have a further 4000 miles to use there, perhaps on your own domestic flights or in South Africa or South America.]

---

## Technical explanation.

Round the world fares are issued by airline alliances. The difficulty you are experiencing is that the Santiago/SCL to Fa'a'ā/PPT route, via Easter Island/IPC, is operated exclusively by LATAM Chile (LA), a member of oneworld. Therefore you need to purchase a oneworld round-the-world fare. Yet, there are no oneworld carriers linking Fa'a'ā/PPT to Australasia. Air Tahiti Nui (TN), a non-aligned carrier, operates a service to Auckland/AKL from Fa'a'ā/PPT, and does so under a Qantas (QF) codeshare.

Oneworld issues several round-the-world and circle continent products. The one you see on rtw.oneworld.com displays the `xONEx` product, the more popular oneworld round-the-world fare. However the oneworld explorer fare is restricted to oneworld carriers only.

The other oneworld fare family, the oneworld *global* explorer fare family, includes the following provision allowing travel on TN, provided it is under the Qantas (QF) codeshare (rule K in the Flight Applications category):

```
  K/TRAVEL ON ANY AA/ AB/ AS/ AY/ BA/ BL/ CX/ EI/
    FJ/ GK/ HG/ IB/ IG/ JJ/ JL/ JQ/ KA/ LA/ MH/ NU/
    PG/ QF/ QR/ RJ/ S7/ UL/ WS/ XL/ 3K/ 4M
    CODESHARE SERVICE OPERATED BY AA/ AB/ AS/ AY/
    BA/ BL/ CX/ EI/ FJ/ GK/ HG/ IB/ IG/ JJ/ JL/
    JQ/ KA/ LA/ MH/ NU/ PG/ QF/ QR/ RJ/ S7/ UL/ WS/
    XL/ 3K/ 4M IS PERMITTED.
    EXCEPTION - JL FLIGHTS OPERATED BY GK ARE NOT
    PERMITTED.
    ALL OTHER CODESHARE FLIGHTS ARE NOT PERMITTED
    WITH THE EXCEPTION OF QF CODESHARE SERVICES
    OPERATED BY AIR TAHITI NUI-TN
```

If your travel agent claims that TN is not permitted because of earlier provisions in the fare that appear to exclude it, please draw this paragraph to her attention.

[Note that the `xONEx` fare family does not include this rule; its provisions are restricted to oneworld carriers and their affiliates:

```
  J.TRAVEL ON ANY AA/AB/AY/BA/CX/HG/IB/JJ/JL/KA/LA/
    MH/NU/QF/QR/RJ/S7/UL/XL/4M CODESHARE SERVICE
    OPERATED BY AA/AB/AY/BA/CX/HG/IB/JJ/JL/KA/LA/MH/
    NU/QF/QR/RJ/S7/UL/XL/4M IS PERMITTED. OTHER
    CODESHARE SERVICES NOT PERMITTED WITH THE
    EXCEPTION OF QF CODESHARE SERVICES OPERATED BY
    JETSTAR /JQ /
    -
    ADDITIONALLY TRAVEL PERMITTED ON THE FOLLOWING
    AIRLINES WHICH ARE AFFILIATED WITH/OR WETLEASE
    PROVIDERS TO ONEWORLD 
    (snipped)
```

End note.]

Comment: something else to keep in mind is that Tahiti to Easter Island is only once a week. Easter Island to Santiago is daily though.